# Ping an external IP in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am making a pinging app on Android as part of a practice project and I am quite stuck doing the real "pinging" thing. I have dug around the stack looking for a "Kotlin" way to do it since I am very new to this. But I ended up finding only Java code like this:

```
private boolean executeCommand(){
    System.out.println("executeCommand");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try
    {
        Process  mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
        System.out.println(" mExitValue "+mExitValue);
        if(mExitValue==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ignore)
    {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" Exception:"+ignore);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" Exception:"+e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried recreating it in Kotlin but everything turns to red in my IDE.
I know it's not easy work but I would really appreciate if you guys helped me find a direct way to ping a host then retrieve the ping value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that a ping is just an [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) `ECHO` request, I think the easiest way to do that would just be to use [`InetAddress.isReachable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress#isReachable(int)).

According to the Javadoc:

> `public boolean isReachable (int timeout)`
>
> Test whether that address is reachable. Best effort is made by the
> implementation to try to reach the host, but firewalls and server
> configuration may block requests resulting in a unreachable status
> while some specific ports may be accessible.
>
> Android implementation attempts ICMP ECHO REQUESTs first, on failure
> it will fall back to TCP ECHO REQUESTs. Success on either protocol
> will return true.

Comment: Now that's a concise way to put it! The documentation says that it tries ICMP followed by TCP REQUEST upon failure, which is exactly what I need. The problem is that this returns a boolean, right ? I am not sure if I am understanding correctly, but is there a way to return a value? I have also read somewhere that I can execute Android ping commands then parse the value. Does that require root and is it as efficient ?

Comment: I took a bit of a dive into the Android source code, and it would definitely not be trivial to to get the response time. You could try with a couple of different timeouts to check whether there is a response within the timeout. No idea about executing OS level ping commands.

Answer (score 0):

[icmp4a](https://github.com/marsounjan/icmp4a) (my library) is what you are looking for. It is an Android implementation of ICMP ping which let you to measure ping accurately.

Example:

1. **Get the library**

```
implementation "com.marsounjan:icmp4a:1.0.0"
```

2. **Single ICMP Ping**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  val status = icmp.ping( host = "8.8.8.8")
  val result = status.result
  when (result) {
    is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
    is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
  }
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:22:48.515 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 12 ms
```

3. **Multiple ICMP Pings with specified interval**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  icmp.pingInterval(
      "8.8.8.8",
      count = 5,
      intervalMillis = 1000
  )
    .onEach { status ->
        val result = status.result
        when (result) {
          is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
          is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
        }
    }
      .launchIn(viewModelScope)
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:29:16.633 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:17.577 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:18.598 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:19.614 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:20.630 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 13 ms
```